# Why isn't jQuery binding with click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Why isn't jQuery binding to the click event?  When I click the selects, they don't alert, except for the one that I put onClick on.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Robo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">

$('.changer').click(function(){alert('test');});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<select class="changer" name="dept" id="dept_select">
    <option value="">Select a Department</option>
</select>

<select onclick="alert('ya');" class="changer" name="course" id="course_select">
    <option value="">Select a Course</option>
</select>
<select class="changer" name="section" id="section_select">
    <option value="">Select a Section</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the .changer elements are not available in the dom when you are binding the click handlers.
You can do two things:

Use jQuery ready event handler

```
 $.ready(function(){
      $('.changer').click(function(){
        alert('test');
      });
    });
```

or  Use live function.

```
$('.changer').live("click", (function(){
   alert('test');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your code in [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$(function(){
  $('.changer').click(function(){alert('test');});
});
```

Comment: oh, silly of me to forget about ready.  its been a while. Thanks, i'm upvoting everyone and will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your jQuery in a ready event:

```
$(function() {
    $('.changer').click(function(){alert('test');});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use delegate function...

```
$('.changer').delegate('click',function(){
   alert('test'); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap syntax dg **.ready** handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('.changer').click(function(){alert('test');});
});
</script>
```

It's method used to specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.